# Why can't a specific BLE peripheral service be discovered?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I'm scanning with following code:

```
self.centralManager?.scanForPeripherals(withServices: serviceUUID, options: nil)
```

This works just fine (my `tableview` gets populated with BLE devices) if I either replace `serviceUUID` with `nil` or define it as

```
let serviceUUID = [CBUUID(string:"1803")]
```

But it will not work with

```
let serviceUUID = [CBUUID(string:"00001803-494c-4f47-4943-544543480000")]
```

Doublechecked with Lightblue, but the service UUID doesn't seem to have any typos.
[Lightblue screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3jBe.png)

Comment: You can scan looking for servicesUUID, it has be broadcasted by the device, meaning it has to be found in the advertisementData of the peripheral. If not, it won't be found. But devices often don't broadcast all the UUID, they often broadcast one or two specifics (to know for instance, that they are from that company, or the kind of device giving for instance that they have the kind of service of blood pressure, etc.)

Comment: Try with `let serviceUUID = [CBUUID(string:"00001803-494C-4F47-4943-544543480000")]`, uppercase for letters? I don't remember if it was case-sensitive or not. Or just use `nil` in options, logs the advertisementData in `didDiscoverPeripheral:` and copy-paste here the value found.

Comment: thanks Larme, tried the uppercase and same result, not case-sensitive. I'll try your advise and work from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Larme has already given the appropriate solution, but I will formulate it as an answer instead of a comment because the comment was probably overlooked.

You scan for peripherals that expose a specific service in their advertisement data. That means that the whole string `00001803-494c-4f47-4943-544543480000` has to be part of the advertisement data. If there is no device found, but if it works for `1803`, it seems that only `1803` is broadcasted by the devices as service information.

Please check the advertisement data of the devices. If they only expose the 16-bit UUID, you have found the reason for the problem.

Remember that advertisement data is limited to a length of 31 bytes, and this is further reduced by the length and data type declarations for each item. So it is quite common to only broadcast 16-bit UUIDs and not waste a large part of the payload for a 128-bit UUID.

Comment: Thanks Nebr - I added a screenshot link taken from Lightblue in the original question from the advertised service; the whole string is broadcasted.

Comment: If I understand the screenshot correctly, the item "Service UUIDs" just contains the string "1803". And that is the item that is checked against parameter serviceUUID. That is why 1803 works, but the full 128-bit UUID does not work.

Comment: I was so focussed on seeing all these 128-bit UUID's that I indeed not considered the service UUID 1803 to be 'the' UUID to look for, I was looking at the (full 128-bit) UUID's just under the advertisement data section - thanks a lot Nebr !

Answer (score 0):

I believe the 128-bit UUID version of `0x1803` would be `00001803-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB`.  Is Light Blue showing you this value under "Advertisement Data (Service UUIDs)" or is it showing you `00001803-494c-4f47-4943-544543480000`?  Because regardless of the *actual* service UUID that the device responds to via GATT, `scanForPeripherals` is only going to return devices with the specified service UUID in the *advertisement data*.

Comment: Yes, Lightblue is showing the exact service UUID; I have added a link to a screenshot in the original post. PS: I gave your suggestion on the 128-bit version a try but nothing picked up.